# Stalling a program without Threads

Tags: java, for-loop, sleep, thread-sleep

I'm working on this video game with a bunch of monsters that run across the screen. The problem is at one point the monster goes past an area (goes above a y-coordinate) and has to go all the way back up to the top. I've received a suggestion to make this transfer from bottom to top delayed by a random amount of time (0, 1, 2, or 3 seconds). Right now, it just goes up to the top without any break whatsoever. My problem is implementing this break. I tried various methods such as stalling with a loop, as shown below

```
            // if( monster is below 400 on y-axis
        if( sbgBackFootY[ i ] >= 400 ) {
            // random number that determines how long it will take to go to top
            int randCo = ( int ) ( Math.random() * 3 );

            if( randCo == 0 ) {
                //moves monster to top
                sbgHeadX[ i ] = 200;
                sbgHeadY[ i ] = 80;
                sbgMouthX[ i ] = 206;
                sbgMouthY[ i ] = 110;
                sbgBackX[ i ] = 190;
                sbgBackY[ i ] = 95;
                sbgBackFootX[ i ] = 190;
                sbgBackFootY[ i ] = 115;
                sbgFrontFootX[ i ] = 197;
                sbgFrontFootY[ i ] = 115;
                sbgLeftEyeX[ i ] = 205;
                sbgLeftEyeY[ i ] = 90;
                sbgRightEyeX[ i ] = 215;
                sbgRightEyeY[ i ] = 90;
                sbgLeftEyebrowStartX[ i ] = 203;
                sbgLeftEyebrowStartY[ i ] = 83;
                sbgLeftEyebrowEndX[ i ] = 210;
                sbgLeftEyebrowEndY[ i ] = 90;
                sbgRightEyebrowStartX[ i ] = 220;
                sbgRightEyebrowStartY[ i ] = 83;
                sbgRightEyebrowEndX[ i ] = 215;
                sbgRightEyebrowEndY[ i ] = 90;

            }

            if( randCo == 1 ) {
                //loop is supposed to stall program 
                for( int w = 0; w <= 1000000000; w++ ){
                    SBGco[ i ]++;
                }

                if( SBGco[ i ] == 1000000000 ) {
                    //moves monster to top
                    sbgHeadX[ i ] = 200;
                    sbgHeadY[ i ] = 80;
                    sbgMouthX[ i ] = 206;
                    sbgMouthY[ i ] = 110;
                    sbgBackX[ i ] = 190;
                    sbgBackY[ i ] = 95;
                    sbgBackFootX[ i ] = 190;
                    sbgBackFootY[ i ] = 115;
                    sbgFrontFootX[ i ] = 197;
                    sbgFrontFootY[ i ] = 115;
                    sbgLeftEyeX[ i ] = 205;
                    sbgLeftEyeY[ i ] = 90;
                    sbgRightEyeX[ i ] = 215;
                    sbgRightEyeY[ i ] = 90;
                    sbgLeftEyebrowStartX[ i ] = 203;
                    sbgLeftEyebrowStartY[ i ] = 83;
                    sbgLeftEyebrowEndX[ i ] = 210;
                    sbgLeftEyebrowEndY[ i ] = 90;
                    sbgRightEyebrowStartX[ i ] = 220;
                    sbgRightEyebrowStartY[ i ] = 83;
                    sbgRightEyebrowEndX[ i ] = 215;
                    sbgRightEyebrowEndY[ i ] = 90;

                }
            }
```

But the computer computes too fast, so the w variable becomes 1000000000 way too fast. The other way to do this is by making threads and going Thread.sleep(randCo) or something, but I am trying to not multi-thread. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off precomputing a path for your sprite and then assign it a velocity. Then, during your "draw" step you compute the location based on the sprite's path, velocity, and time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Thread.sleep(..) is your best option. If you have one thread and you put it to sleep doesn't mean that you have multi-threading.

Comment: Don't think he can thread sleep. If I understand him correct, the single thread renders *all* his monsters so if you thread sleep, all monsters will stop (as opposed to just the ones travelling the boundaries)

Comment: @Michael On a second read of the question, I think you're right. He should go with Andrew's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep time of how long he has been off the screen, and then put him back when he is back on the screen:

```
int initTime= 0;
int elapsedTimeOffScreen = 0

if( sbgBackFootY[ i ] >= 400 ) {
if(initTime!= 0)
   initTime= DateTime.Now;
elapsedTimeOfScreen  = DateTime.Now - initTime;

if(elapsedTimeOffscreen > 1000)
{
  initTime = 0
  elapsedTimeOffScreen = 0;
 //go back on screen
}
```

initTime will get reset each time the character 
This will use time to check how long the character has been off the screen for. It's certainly much more reliable than using cpu cycles.

Comment: Don't be discouraged, yours was also good. I used the part where you suggested to use the system time. Thank you.